# X-position of the window changes with the browser window change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am an absolute beginner to Java Script. My task is to make an interactive radio where a song is played if a mouse is in a certain position on the map. It works but only in a certain size of the browser window. If I change the size the "song positions" are misplaced.

I am using p5 libraries.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Canvas Trial</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"> </script>
    <script src="../p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <center><p class="title">CHRISTMAS RADIO</p></center>

    <div class="radio" id="clickArea" onmousemove="trackMouse()"> 
        <img id="radio" onclick="rotate()"  src="images/radio.png""></img>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
canvas{
    background-image: url("images/Map1.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;

    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;

    border:solid 2px;
    border-bottom-color:#ffe;
    border-left-color:#eed;
    border-right-color:#eed;
    border-top-color:#ccb;
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;

}

p.title{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 250%;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: -2px 0 #c61819, 0 2px #c61819, 2px 0 #c61819, 0 -2px #c61819;
}

.radio{
    position:relative;
    top: 10%;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    border: solid 2px;
    border-color:#52361b;
    padding:0;
    width: 944px;
    height:165px;

}
```

This is my Java Script:

```
var x = "";
var y = "";
var song1;
var song2;


function preload() {
  song1 = loadSound('audio/2.mp3');
  song2 = loadSound('audio/3.mp3');
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(944,566);
}

function draw() {
    clear();
    x = mouseX;

  rect(x, y, 20, 565);
  fill(82, 54, 27);

}

function trackMouse(){
var x = event.clientX;
console.log(window.screenX);


if(x>315&&x<340){
song1.loop();
document.getElementById("clickArea").style.backgroundColor="white";

} else {
song1.stop();
document.getElementById("clickArea").style.backgroundColor="black";
    } 

if(x>400&&x<450){
song2.loop();
document.getElementById("clickArea").style.backgroundColor="#FFDAB9";


} else {
song2.stop();
document.getElementById("clickArea").style.backgroundColor="black";
    } 


}

//document.getElementById("canvas").style.background-image="url("images/Map2.png")";
```

Do you have any suggestions/advices?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're using absolute values in `pixels` for locating the areas on the radio map and you're accessing them in var x. You would need relative values that is in `percentage` to have them constant even when the browser is resized.

You can try doing it by: getting the `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`, store it in variables say `v1 and v2`, that is your 100%. Now to obtain `relative position coordinates`, divide the current position you're using say 315 by it and multiply by 100.

> Example : Say the width is 1200 pixels at maximize then, 315 is 26.25%
>   of 1200. That's the value you will use and it will work even when the
>   browser is resized.
>
> ```
> (Absolute coodinate/ Complete width at maximized screen) X 100 = relative coordinate
>
> (315/1200)x100 = 26.25%
> ```

Remember to make the changes to your code according to that and it should work fine. Hope, it gives you the idea.